# Activities - Android Studio Programming

Tags: android-studio

I'm developing an app on android studio, just for practice, and wanted to make a dog breed app. The main screen will be a scrollview with pictures of all the different breeds and you can click the picture to find out more information about the breed.

I was going to create a new activity for each breed, which would leave me with 189 different activities. Is this the correct way to handle this? Will having this many activities slow performance and if so what is the correct way to code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.. the correct way sholud be using fragments to dinamically load your content

```
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html
```

Comment: Thank you for the information! This is exactly what I needed.